# How to cache and persist the temporary tables in Spark SQL?

Tags: caching, python-import, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have working code for reading a text file and using as a registered temporary table in memory. I would like to load a set of these tables using a script or a module import and then query them interactively. If if put this code into a script and a function, which is the object I should return? The sc context? The table? The HadoopRDD?

```
file = "/file.tsv"
lines = sc.textFile(file)
parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split("\t")).filter(lambda line:len(line)==7)

active_sessions = parts.map(lambda p: Row( 
    session=p[0]
    , user_id=p[1]
    , created=p[2]
    , updated=p[3]
    , id=p[4]
    , deleted=p[5]
    , resource_id=p[6]))

schemaTable = sqlContext.inferSchema(active_sessions)
schemaTable.registerTempTable("active_sessions")
sqlContext.cacheTable("active_sessions")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up returning:

```
return sqlContext.table("active_sessions")
```

I had registered it as a table rather than a temptable though, but it works with temptables as well.

Comment: what is the difference between a temporary table and just a table? Does a table get stored into cache while a temporary table does not?